# Label Arrow with tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

This is a super simple problem, but I can't figure out how to add a label to an arrow between two nodes. Right now, the code I have seems to add an extra node in between the nodes I wish to connect and labels that node what I want to label the arrow (and it makes a mess). How can I do this properly?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, every node/.style={circle, fill=blue!20, minimum size=15mm}]
\node (A) at (0, 1) {A};
\node (B) at (-1, -.5) {B};
\node (C) at (1, -.5) {C};
\draw [thick, ->] (A) to node[left] {-10} (B);
\draw [thick, ->] (A) to node[left] {15} (C);
\draw [thick, ->] (B) to node[left] {20] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This is (probably) due to all the `to node[left] {-10}` things.

Comment: Well yeah, but that's what I've seen people use in examples online...

Comment: Try `\draw [thick, ->] (A) -- (B);
\draw [thick, ->] (A)  -- (C);
\draw [thick, ->] (B) -- (C);` instead.

Comment: But how do I add a little label on the arrows with the numbers?

Comment: I guess what you saw was maybe `\draw [thick, ->] (A) to[bend left=-10] (B);
\draw [thick, ->] (A) to [bend left=15] (C);
\draw [thick, ->] (B) to [bend left=20] (C);

Comment: Well yes, but how could I add a *label* on the arrows?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Too long for a comment. With `every node/.style={...}` you instructed Ti*k*Z to draw *all* nodes with a fat bullet, but it seems like you don't want this to happen for the numbers. So one way to go is

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, fatnode/.style={circle, fill=blue!20, minimum size=15mm}]
\node[fatnode] (A) at (0, 1) {A};
\node[fatnode] (B) at (-1, -.5) {B};
\node[fatnode] (C) at (1, -.5) {C};
\draw [thick, ->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,above left] {-10};
\draw [thick, ->] (A) -- (C) node[midway,above right] {15};
\draw [thick, ->] (B) -- (C) node[midway,above] {20};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is my final upvote.